# How to set timeout for getConnection using commons-dbcp BasicDataSource?

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am using commons-dbcp2 for creating a connection pool to the database. When the database is down `dataSource.getConnection()` method takes 20 seconds then throws an exception. I want to configure `DataSource` to dynamically change the timeout e.g. 5 seconds.

I tried `dataSource.setLoginTimeout()`, but it is not supported for  `BasicDataSource`

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverName);       
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(username);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
dataSource.setInitialSize(3);
dataSource.setMaxTotal(100);  
dataSource.setValidationQuery(validationquery);
dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow(true);

try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

I want after 5 seconds (as I configured) it throws the exception.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`validationQueryTimeout` parameter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) which lets you time out the validation query after X seconds:

```
dataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(5);
dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
```

You don't have to set a validation SQL query, modern JDBC driver has `Connection.isValid()`.

Unfortunately DBCP pool has issues as per [Bad Behavior: Handling Database Down](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Bad-Behavior:-Handling-Database-Down) due to operating system TCP timeout limit. When the test was done in 2017:

> Dbcp2 did not return a connection, and also did not timeout. The execution of the validation query is stuck due to unacknowledged TCP traffic. Subsequently, the SQL Statement run on the (bad) connection by the test harness hangs (due to unacknowledged TCP). setMaxWait(5000) is seemingly useless for handling network outages. There are no other meaningful timeout settings that apply to a network failure.

Comment: Thank you Karol. I have changed the connection pool to HikariCp. Timeout works properly, but sometimes I am getting the following exception: 
`Exception during pool initialization. 
java.sql.SQLException: (conn=39) Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'`. do you have any idea how it happens?

Comment: Please open a new question with full stack trace from the `Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'` exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `datasource.setValidationQueryTimeout()`, but keep in mind that this is for query execution. If you have network issues, you might still be stuck. For this, you need to set also `setSoTimeout()`, which is for the socket. The default value is 0, which means infinity.